# Binder has been finalized when using Facebook's Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook's SDK for Android (latest version as of today). The code that is for authentication is the following:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
String fbAccessToken = prefs.getString("fb_access_token", null);
long fbAccessExpires = prefs.getLong("fb_access_expires", 0);
if (fbAccessToken != null) {
    facebook.setAccessToken(fbAccessToken);
}
if (fbAccessExpires != 0) {
    facebook.setAccessExpires(fbAccessExpires);
}
if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
    facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "friends_birthday" }, new DialogListener() {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = prefs.edit();
            prefEditor.putString("fb_access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
            prefEditor.putLong("fb_access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
            prefEditor.commit();
            // do some graph requests
        }
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
        }
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });
}
else {
    // do some graph requests
}
```

Unfortunately, the Facebook app opens upon that request and shows "Loading ...". A few seconds later, it just disappears without any result.

In LogCat, I can then read the following exception:

```
12-11 21:04:34.597: E/System(29584): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:288)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1591)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize(ContentResolver.java:1604)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
12-11 21:04:34.613: E/System(29584):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Is this a common problem with Facebook SDK? I don't think so, haven't found anything about that. What causes this problem?

Comment: That exception is definitely very odd and possibly not even related to our android sdk. can you try running the hackbook example (as seen in the samples folder of the sdk download) and verify the same issue?  Make sure to add your key hash to your app dashboard because that is required when using native SSO.  Also make sure your facebook app is up to date.

Comment: The Exception looks database-related. Is your app opening or closing a database at the same time your doing FB auth?

Comment: If you have the whole dump, do check if the pid 29584 is same as your appś logs. Chances are that this is a completely unrelated to facebook sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ensure you are using the final version of the SDK 3.0 (which we just released), available at https://developers.facebook.com/android

Also make sure you have Java 1.6 and a clean project/workspace.

I'd advise you to use the contemporary patterns for Session handling and login, as described in the documentation on that site.

Comment: Now I'm using your latest SDK (3.0), and the error does not occur anymore. Thank you!