# IllegalStateException when trying to use facebook android API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, exception, authentication

I'm trying to use the Facebooks API for android to make a login function in my app....

I've followed this tutorial http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example

And copied the exact same code... it took me a time to discover that there wasn't nothing wrong with my code...

But, whenever I click the login button I get an exception and the login performs but when the app is returned the session is not opened.

In the logcat I got this.

```
04-22 22:11:15.570  31114-31122/com.myapppackage.app E/System﹕ Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
04-22 22:11:15.570  31114-31122/com.myapppackage.app E/System﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
            at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:288)
            at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
            at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49)
            at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1591)
            at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize(ContentResolver.java:1604)
            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?
I'm using latest facebook SDK (3.8) with android studio... I'm pretty sure I configured the SDK right because the test sample in Facebook's page works (get the name of a profile)... but login isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to clean the project and check your AppId.
See this question of stack overflow related to your problem.

[Binder has been finalized when using Facebook's Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827724/binder-has-been-finalized-when-using-facebooks-android-sdk)

Hope it will help.

Comment: I've checked this question before posting... but it's a bit old... the creator said that when he updated to 3.0 it was fixed... but i'm using 3.8 already...